# Find all elements by xpath attribute (aria-required = true) .//*[@aria-required='true']

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a list of IwebElements that contain the attribute aria-required. Reason why I'm trying to get this list, is so that i can check if all required fields are necessary for the user to fill out, before he can continue to the next page.

So far after 2 days of searching I'm still convinced that it shouldn't be that hard. I'm using the expression:

".//*[@aria-required='true']"

From my research that would mean that it will search for ALL the elements starting from the root of my webdriver.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CreateProjectWithoutRequiredFields()
    {
        GoToProjectPage();
        tracking = CM.GoToNewlyCreatedFrameAfterClickButton("ftbNew", tracking, theDriver);
        CM.Wait(2000);
        bool succesSave = false;
        CM.LogToFile("Create project whitout required fields", tracking);
        foreach (IWebElement e in theDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@aria-required='true']")))
        {

            FillDataInNewProjectPage();
            e.Clear();
            CM.GetDynamicElementById("btnSave", theDriver).Click();
            try
            {
                CM.GetDynamicElementById("titel", theDriver).Click();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                succesSave = true;
                NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsFalse(succesSave, "The page is saved with succes, without entering text in the following required fields : " + e.GetAttribute("id").ToString());

            }
            CM.Wait(1000);
        }
```

}

I will try to explain what i did here:
First i went to a overview page with all my existing projects. On this page i clicked the ftbNew button to create a new project. The driver is automatically switch to the correct frame (i now the right frame is selected because i used this line on other page's.)

then the line
    foreach (IWebElement e in theDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@aria-required='true']")))
        {

should normaly find a the elements in my driver with an attribute "aria-required='true'"

Then it would fill in the page with data, clear the first element that is found from its data en try to save it.

if the element titel is found on the page, than we are still on the same page en the save action wasn't successful ( <- so this is good)

so next we again overwrite every field on the page and clear this time the second element that is found.

en so on...

What I'm guessing, that xpath has difficulty finding the 'old' aria-required attribute... When i try to validate my expression using firebug and other xpath checkers, the aria-required attribute isn't always present. Sometimes it finds the input field sometimes it doesn't.

[source code page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMqzD.jpg)

As you can see in the firebug console not all attributes are loaded, account-manager has a aria-required attribute, but project leader doesn't. If i inspect the element again, but this time click project leader. The attribute will be loaded. Very strange....

Extra info: I am using frame's and i know a lot can go wrong if you are situated in the wrong frame, but i am sure that he is looking in the correct frame. Especially because i can't find the elements using firebug with the above expression. If i change my expression to .//input, it will find the elements but also selects input fields that aren't required.

In advance i want to thank everybody that want to look into my problem :)
Adriaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the behavior on the page, you cannot rely on the aria-required attribute to indicate a required field.  I think that you should go back to the developers of the site to ask them to give you a reliable handle.  It may be as simple as looking for the "*" as the last character of the label associated with the input field, but that's kind of annoying to have to deal with.

As an aside, you should consider catching a more specific exception for your success case.  Right now, if ANY exception happens, you'll declare success, but that may not be what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks for replying that fast!
You are wright about that exception, i had to be more specific.

About the expression, i asked them if they could use instead of "aria-required" use "required", but they say it is to much work.... So i tried to get the elements through a css class ("verplichteControl" means "requiredControl") (In my initial post i have a image )

now i do get the elements with the following expression.
".//*[contains(@class, 'verplichteControl')]"

So it works... But still curious why you can't select elements by their attribute.

Comment: Oh, you can select an element by it's attributes.  The problem here is that your application is not consistently applying the aria-required attribute.  For example, I don't see it in the Project Leader input in the image you included.  Come to think of it, perhaps there's a product defect here, if it is too much work for the developers (which it shouldn't be at all!), they should at least get it right for the attributes that they are trying to use.